# Managing a maintainance page redirect in an ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config, global-asax

I would like to use a configuration in the .config file like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SiteIsActive" value="false"/>
  <add key="SiteNonActive_RedirectTo" value="UnderMaintainance.aspx"/>
</appSettings>
```

So that, when the setting is set to the false value, the system automatically redirects EVERY REQUEST to the maintainance page.

I tried to do this in this way: using Global.asax's Application_BeginRequest:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if ((bool)System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteIsActive"])
    if (this.Request.Path.IndexOf(
       System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteNonActive_RedirectTo"]) == -1)
      this.Response.Redirect(
      System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteNonActive_RedirectTo"]);
}
```

Basically it works, but when redirecting in this way, firefox will show me the page WITHOUT any image or style applied... it's strange, I look at the page source downloaded by the browser and everything is there!

Is this the right way to achieve my objective?
Do I do anything wrong?

Thankyou

PS: Internet Explorer does not behave like firefox, it shows me the redirected page correctly.

PS2: You guys correctly posted me that a feature called App_Offline is available. Well, I would like not using it for one reason: I would like to use my maintainance page not only to show one status, but more statuses, for example:

1) Maintainance

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SiteIsActive" value="false"/>
  <add key="SiteNonActive_RedirectTo" value="UnderMaintainance.aspx?S=Maintainance"/>
</appSettings>
```

2) Under construction

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SiteIsActive" value="false"/>
  <add key="SiteNonActive_RedirectTo" value="UnderMaintainance.aspx?S=UnderConstr"/>
</appSettings>
```

3) Temporary inactivity

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SiteIsActive" value="false"/>
  <add key="SiteNonActive_RedirectTo" value="UnderMaintainance.aspx?S=TempInact"/>
</appSettings>
```

App_Offline does not offer me this.

Comment: Have you checked out App_Offline.html? Just a tip.

Comment: I think you're over complicating this. You could just keep three different App_Offline pages on the site: `App_Offline.maint`, App_Offline.under` and `App_Offline.temp`. Rename the one that applies to `App_Offline.htm`. It means you can ensure that your .aspx page is never at risk of not running should you muck up a web.config setting for example, or drop a DLL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a much simpler way to do this and it uses a special page called `App_Offline.htm`.

For more information:

> [App_Offline.htm - by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx)

You might also want to read the follow up by Scott about a gotcha with IE6:

> [App_Offline.htm and working around the "IE Friendly Errors" feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx)

When not in use just rename it to something like `App_offline.disabled` then when you need to do maintenance rename it back to `App_Offline.htm` again.

A further justification for this approach is that if your "maintenance" includes deploying the site or editing your `web.config`, your `UnderMaintainance.aspx` page may fail to execute because your site will be in a state of flux whilst it is being uploaded. Or, you may have made a mistake and overwritten these "maintenance" values in your `web.config`.

`App_Offline.htm` is great because it means you can really mess up your deployment and no-one will know.